# Driver for SoftKinetic DS325 / DS311

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a ROS driver for the [SoftKinetic](http://softkinetic.com) [DS325](http://www.softkinetic.com/Store/tabid/579/ProductID/6/language/en-US/Default.aspx) or [DS311](http://www.softkinetic.com/Store/tabid/579/ProductID/2/language/en-US/Default.aspx) 3D sensors?

They do have Linux support (basic driver only), so I'm just trying make sure I don't start working on something that already exists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115841/driver-for-softkinetic-ds325-/-ds311/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit (2014-06-10): it would seem a driver is available in the [ipa320/softkinetic](https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic) Github repository now. I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be at least publishing `sensor_msgs::Image` and `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` messages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0